# I am looking for a way to determine the rotation of an electric motor externally as i can not see the shaft

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I am looking for a way to determine the rotation of an electric motor externally as i can not see the shaft the outside of the motor is smooth all the way around. is there sufficient magnetic field to have a pull on a magnetic ball?

Comment: As it stands this question does not have enough information to be answered

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the motor is not mounted (not fixed to a much larger body) can you detect a tendency of the motor-body to rotate at the time when when the motor is connected to its power supply? If so, in accordance with the conservation of angular momentum, the shaft will be rotating in the opposite sense.

Comment: The pump/motor are mounted so no we cant detect a "Kick back" opposite to the rotation

Comment: Is the pump pumping a gas or a liquid? If a liquid you might see some swirling motion in the pump outflow. But I expect you're going to say that you can't see then outflow!